# Dynamic ListView extends Activity

Tags: android, listview, dynamic, android-activity, listactivity

Is there anyway I can create a dynamically filled `ListView` when the class does not extend `ListActivity`?

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Example:

```
public class StoreListActivity extends Activity {
    private List<Store> mStores;
    private StoreAdapter mStoreAdapter;
    private ListView mListView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.store_list);
        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.store_listview);

            mStores = getTheStoresFromSomewhere();
        mStoreAdapter = new StoreAdapter(this, mStores);
        mListView.setAdapter(mStoreAdapter);
    }
```

Comment: Could an array adapter be used as-well?

Comment: :D  Got it working.  Thanks everyone! Although I might have another question which I'll post later.

Comment: @Mitchell: Actually `StoreAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Store>`